# In react, can I retrieve out from ReactElement an array of all src from any <img> tags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the render function in a react component. After JSX has been parsed, the value of renderHandle is a ReactElement.

The comment marks the spot where I want to retrieve an array of all src from any  tags within the ReactElement. How do I do this?

```
 render: function() {
      var renderHandle = 
      <div id="madmaxpage">                
           <img src={webroot+'images/madmax.jpg'}/>
           <img src={webroot+'images/furiosa.jpg'}/>
           <p>
                <img src={webroot+'images/witnessme.jpg'}/>
           </p>
      </div> 
      // take a look at the ReactElement
      console.log(renderHandle);
      // Here is where I want to retrieve the 
      // array of src and log it to the console
      return(
           renderHandle
      );
 }
```

Comment: I suppose this is a contrived example since those image paths are static so there'd be no reason to log them. But why don't you put them in an array to begin with so you can log the array? Then `<img src={myArray[0]}/>` etc.

Comment: yes thats correct. The situation is constructed to convey my question easily. In fact i'm interested in extracting all src no matter how deep. I'll edit the question so one of the <img> tags is deeper

Comment: Use case: At runtime we want to alter the src to include environment variable for path in cdn